# Which Language like Instant Messenger Server

Tags: xmpp

I want to run Cross-Platform XMPP Instant Messenger. What Server-Side language should I choose?

Comment: Why would you write your own XMPP server? There are already plenty around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a XMPP server, take a look at [Ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/)(written in Erlang) or maybe [Tigase](http://www.tigase.org/)(written in Java)

If you want to create your own, use:

- Twisted Matrix, a Python framework to develop asynchronous applications
- Erlang, a functional language designed with concurrency in mind.
- Java with the NIO asynchronous library

Depending on how close to the XMPP spec you want to be, C++ might be an option but it will be quite challenging, as there is a fair amount of logic to implement :-)

If you want to optimize for speed, identify the bottlenecks of your application, and look into writing specific parts in C(XML parsing or string handling).

Answer (score 2):

There's also http://prosody.im/ which uses Lua. Their mission statement:

> Prosody is a modern flexible communications server for Jabber/XMPP written in Lua. It aims to be easy to set up and configure, and light on resources. For developers it aims to be easy to extend and give a flexible system on which to rapidly develop added functionality, or prototype new protocols.
>
> Prosody is licensed under the permissive MIT/X11 license.